# Quickblox video chat - Missing audio

Tags: quickblox, videochat, libjingle

I have upgraded my Android app from Quickblox Version 2.6.0 to 3.3.0. I am now experiencing the issue of missing audio on my video calls. It seems to be an outbound issue, as I have tested the app in interaction with the old version. In the logs i can see following error:

```
E/libjingle: (stunport.cc:283): Jingle:Port[0xb850ea58:audio:1:0:local:Net[lo:127.0.0.0/8:Loopback]]: UDP send of 96 bytes failed with error 22
```

Has anybody experienced an similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this issue I shamefully have to admit, that I was missing the proper permission in the AndroidManifest. :P

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

The communication now works as expected. But I still see the errors in the logs. Can anybody shine some light on why they are occuring? Is this only network related (and not preventable)?